# Factory not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test a model with RSpec but I probably have stumbled on a typo that I just can't find. Can somebody please help me a bit? I've been struggling with it for a long time and just can't find any mistakes. Thank you in advance!

user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
     it "has a valid factory" do
        FactoryGirl.build(:user).should be_valid
     end
     it "is invalid without an e-mail"
     it "is invalid without a correct e-mail" 
     it "is invalid without a password" 
     it "is invalid without a matching password confrimation" 
end
```

user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do |f|
        f.email "aabb@hh.de"
        f.password "ruby"
        f.password_confrimation "ruby"
    end
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_girl'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

error

```
Factory not registered: user
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303329/rspec-cant-find-factorys-from-factorygirl. I think you need the factory_girl_rails gem.

Comment: I already have it.
gem list | grep rspec* output is

rspec-rails (2.13.2)

Comment: factory_girl_rails is different than rspec_rails

Comment: Peters-MacBook-Air-2:~ palfvin$ gem list | grep factory
factory_girl (4.1.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)

Comment: Sorry :P
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1) is installed

Comment: So did renaming your factory file to factories.rb take care of it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have your factory definition in the wrong file, according to your question it is in user.rb. This needs to be in a factories.rb in your test folder (spec) if you use rspec

```
# user.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do |f|
        f.email "aabb@hh.de"
        f.password "ruby"
        f.password_confrimation "ruby"
    end
end
```

Change above to this, (Also you don't need the f variable)

```
# spec/factories.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        email "aabb@hh.de"
        password "ruby"
        password_confrimation "ruby"
    end
end
```

Also as the comments say, make sure `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` is in your `Gemfile`, instead of just `gem 'factory_girl'`

Comment: I was apparently wrong about the factories.rb naming, at least based on the test I just did. If you'll make a minor edit to your answer, I'll remove my downvote. Sorry about that.  Could have sworn ....

Comment: The definition could go into `spec/factories/user.rb` and work fine.    That `spec/factories.rb` file could get really bloated over time if you weren't able to split your factory definitions out.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti Agreed. For simplicity, since there was no indication `user.rb` was anywhere near the `spec` folder, I just suggested `factories.rb` because I thought it would be easiest to understand.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I appreciate that. Just for anyone reading this, individual factory files in the test directory or `test/factory/*.rb` are auto picked up. If you want something other than the default, do this `config.generators do |g|; g.factory_girl dir: 'custom/dir/for/factories'; end;`

Comment: Helped me- I had 'factory_girl' not 'factory_girl_rails' - thanks

Comment: I've followed all of the above and added my factories to spec/factories/*.rb, but they still aren't picked up! Any tips?

Comment: In this example, `spec/factories/users.rb` is where this code should go if you don't want to use the default `spec/factories.rb`

Answer (score 1):

I had run into the following issue with the structure in my folder factories/

 `- factories/
 -- artists.rb
 -- techniques.rb`

`artists.rb`

```
FactoryBot.define do
    factory :artist do
      name       'Michael'
      technique   FactoryBot.create :technique
    end
  end
```

`techniques.rb`

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :technique do
    name 'Some name'
  end
end
```

So it was loading artist before technique object were loaded. So it couldn't find it. The solution is to not use nested FactoryBot create in factories or rename your nested factories to something that stands before your parent factory.

I just moved my technique factory. to `factories.rb` and defined it there. And issue was resolved.

Comment: or just add this to your `support/factory_bot.rb` 
`FactoryBot.find_definitions`
in block, that'll do.

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when running the Rails application in the production environment.

Usually, the Gem `factory_bot_rails` is only added here:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'faker'
end
```

You should add these to the "general" list of Gems if you want to use them in production.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only thing I added was a factories.rb file. All tests passed from that.

Answer (score 0):

Move your factory definition:

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user do |f|
    f.email "aabb@hh.de"
    f.password "ruby"
    f.password_confrimation "ruby"
end
```

end

to **"spec/factories/users.rb"**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).